# Undefined reference using external library with CMake and Conan

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, undefined-reference, conan

I am trying to develop a program that communicates with a PCSC USB reader using Conan and CMake with the LibLogicalAccess library. I followed the instructions of building and installing the library which seemed to have gone fine. I created a small simple console project with a "main.cpp" file. Following the [C++ guide](https://github.com/islog/liblogicalaccess/wiki/How-to-Use-Liblogicalaccess) on the wiki of the library I tried to call a function from the library which resulted in a "Undefined reference to *function*. I know there are a lot of topics covering this but I have read as many as I could but could not seem to find the right solution.

I don't have much experience with Ubuntu/CMake/Conan/C++ so it might as well be a very simple fix.

OS:     Kubuntu 18.04 
Lang:   C++ 
Related software: LibLogicalAccess
                  2.2.1, 
                     CMake 3.17.1,
                     Conan 1.25.0

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <logicalaccess/dynlibrary/librarymanager.hpp>
#include <logicalaccess/readerproviders/readerconfiguration.hpp>
#include <logicalaccess/cards/chip.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Program started\n";

    // Reader configuration object to store reader provider and reader unit selection.
    std::shared_ptr<logicalaccess::ReaderConfiguration> readerConfig(new logicalaccess::ReaderConfiguration());

    // Set PCSC ReaderProvider by calling the Library Manager which will load the function from the corresponding plug-in
    readerConfig->setReaderProvider(logicalaccess::LibraryManager::getInstance()->getReaderProvider("PCSC"));

    std::cout << "after..\n";
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(project)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-I /usr/include/PCSC")
add_executable(project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project PUBLIC CONAN_PKG::LogicalAccess)
```

When I try to build the program using `cmake --build .` this is the output:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/project
CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `logicalaccess::LibraryManager::getReaderProvider(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make:191: recipe for target 'bin/project' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/project] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/project.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:103: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The weird part is that the first line of code: `std::shared_ptr<logicalaccess::ReaderConfiguration> readerConfig(...)` works fine and the second line of code gives an undefined reference.

I have tried other functions in the same file which give the same result. The file compiles and runs fine when I remove the last "setReaderProvider" line of code. Also tried a lot of different little adjustments regarding the conanfile.txt and CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: OT: If you don't have an explicit reason to use `std::shared_ptr`, don't. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the commands that you have run? Did you follow the example on: https://github.com/islog/liblogicalaccess/wiki/Build-Liblogicalaccess?
`mkdir build ; cd build ; conan install .. ; cmake build ..`
`cmake --build .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error says:

> main.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `logicalaccess::LibraryManager::getReaderProvider(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'

It occurs because your CMake is using libstdc++11 to link, however, Conan is configured to use libstdc++ due backward compatibility.
You need to update your default libcxx:

```
conan profile update settings.compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 default
```

Please, read this section in Conan docs [How to Manage GCC ABI](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_gcc_abi.html) to get more information.

Also, it's explained on step 5 of [Getting Started](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Now when building again, you will need that your local packages won't be available, because it's a new package, using different settings, so you will need to install, or build from sources. The link to libstdc++11 is automatically managed by Conan, it passes the definitions to CMake.

Regards!

Comment: This fixed my problem, thank you!
I changed the conan profile settings as you stated, rebuilded the library, created a new project, installed conan again and was able to build the project without undefined references.

Comment: That's great! Could you please mark my answer as accepted, so other users can use it as reference.

Comment: Even after updating my profile, I still get the same error. What exactly do you mean "you will need to install, or build from sources". I cleared my cache with `conan remove fmt` and `conan install ..`, but to no avail...